# How to convert Python implementation of Dijsktra algorithm based on "None" distances to "Infinity" distance

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

There are two Dijkstra algorithms (methods) that I implemented in Python the first method I took from this http://jpython.blogspot.com/2015/10/dijkstra-algorithm.html source, the second is created by me and it more fits to C++ style (with checkings and relaxation) - the method that I prefer. The first Dijkstra method works, but the second dijkstra2 always returns 1e9. What's wrong with the second method.

```
from heapq import *

def Dijkstra(graph, source):
     dist = [None] * len(graph)
     queue = [(0, source)]
     while queue:
          c_dist, u = heappop(queue)
          if dist[u] is None:
               dist[u] = c_dist
               for v, length in graph[u].items():
                    if dist[v] is None:
                         heappush(queue, (c_dist + length, v))

     return [-1 if x is None else x for x in dist]


def dijkstra2( graph, source):
     dist = [1e9] * len(graph)
     queue = [(0, source)]
     while queue:
          c_dist, u = heappop(queue)
          if c_dist > dist[u]:
               continue
          for v, length in graph[u].items():
               if dist[v] > dist[u] + length:
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + length
     return [-1 if x is 1e9 else x for x in dist]


graph = {
  0: { 1:2, 2:4, 3:1 },
  1: { 2:1, 3:3 },
  2: { 4: 7},
  3: { 2: 2 },
  4: { 0:2, 3:3 }, 
  5: {}
}
source = 0

print (Dijkstra(graph, source))
```

Comment: Where do you ever add anything to the queue in your implementation?

Comment: Sorry implementation is this

Comment: Yes I see, but still don't work  after adding heappush(queue, (dist[v], v))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 problems in your code:

- As already pointed out by chrisz, you need to add `v` to your queue, otherwise you'll do only one pass in the loop.
- Since the values in dist are updated when putting the nodes in queue, not when popping them, you need to change the source's distance right at the beginning
- The conversion between `1e9` and `-1` at the end is not performed because you need to use `x==1e9` instead of `x is 1e9`.

You can check in any python console that:

```
x=1e9 
x is 1e9
```

returns `False`.

Here is a full working code:

```
def dijkstra2( graph, source):
     INFINITY = 1e9
     dist = [INFINITY] * len(graph)
     queue = [(0, source)]
     dist[source]=  0
     while queue:
          c_dist, u = heappop(queue)
          if c_dist > dist[u]:
               continue
          for v, length in graph[u].items():
               if dist[v] > dist[u] + length:
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + length
                    heappush(queue, (dist[v], v))
     return [-1 if x==INFINITY else x for x in dist]
```